# Why .on('click') fails

Tags: jquery

I load `#content` into a `#container` with jQuery `.load`, and have a `.mybutton` inside the loaded content.

I attach the `click` event to the entire `html`, to make sure that the element exists even before the content has loaded:

```
$("html").on('click', '.mybutton', function(event) {
// do all sorts of stuff
});
```

And yet, every once in a while, one click out of a hundred or so, the button fails to work.

What could be the reason, and how can this be fixed?

Comment: check the console. your code is ok.

Comment: The console can't show stuff that happens inside html that has been loaded with JavaScript, or am I mistaken, @Royi?

Comment: Can u simulate the same on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @KeithRules Try and see. (The console will show anything the Javascript interpreter does.)

Comment: @KeithRules Also, "X fails intermittently" isn't much for anyone to go on. Try to pin down the circumstances of the intermittent failure somehow.

Comment: @KeithRules once the code is injected to your dom , it is a regular code as if you wrote it. except for the handler attached to the html tag.

Comment: I would try binding the event to the `body` instead of `html`

Comment: You're right, of course, @millimoose. The problem is, I've been clicking on those damn buttons for a week, and I still can't distinguish anything special about situations when they do not work. ;-(

Comment: Could you tell me why, @MatteoTassinari?

Comment: Firefox's `Developer Toolbar` is your friend. Javascript debug console, ... lots of good stuffs.

Comment: Well, do some clicks on the same button fail? Do all clicks on one of the buttons fail? If you set a debugger breakpoint at the start of the event handler, does it get hit? If you set up a catch-all event `$("html").on("click", "*", ...);` does it tell you the click event fired at all?

Comment: @KeithRules two reasons: first, personally I'm not sure if `html` can be attached events, second, all your buttons will be in the `body` anyway, this way you save a level of bubbling.

Comment: (Yes, this is the "throw stuff at the wall and see what sticks" school of diagnosis.)

Comment: You're definitely onto something, @millimoose. The event is triggered by clicking on several types of buttons, and only one of them fails every now and then, specifically, only those buttons that are loaded with AJAX. Unfortunately, I'm a JavaScript beginner, and some of the stuff you wrote is a bit new to me - such as, "If you set a debugger breakpoint at the start of the event handler, does it get hit? If you set up a catch-all event $("html").on("click", "*", ...); does it tell you the click event fired at all?" – perhaps you could expand on that by writing an answer?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari `<html>` definitely can have events attached to it, at least in Chrome.

Comment: what jquery version are you using? try replacing `$('html')` with `$(document)`.

Comment: @KeithRules: I think the best place to start would be the Javascript Debugger docs: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: it helps a lot to know what version. try `$(document).on(......)` as it's dynamically added.

Comment: Could you please tell me what could be the advantage of using `(document)` rather than a tag, for example `("html")` or `("body")`, @Omar?

Comment: The general thing you're aiming at here is to find out if: 1. The click event gets fired at all and bubbles all the way to `<html>` - this is what the catch-all event is for. 2. The click event gets correctly delegated to the button - this is what the debugger breakpoint is for. If 1 fails, that means something somewhere else is swallowing the event before it bubbles up. If 1 works but 2 fails, that means delegation broke, and I'd guess the selector expression is broken. If 1 and 2 work, then the problem is somewhere in the event handler, in which case go over it in the debugger.

Comment: @KeithRules ["The `document` element is available in the `head` of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready."](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: yeah, but what the heck IS "catch-all event", @millimoose? ;-) To say nothing of the "debugger breakpoint"?  (Reading the docs now.)

Comment: are you loading it into an iframe?

Comment: Does that mean that it's actually better to attach event to `$(document)` rather than a tag, @millimoose?

Comment: Nope, @Omar. Into a `div`.

Comment: @KeithRules Uhh... I'm not sure it's feasible to teach you how to use debuggers over SO comments. The catch-all event handler would be `$(document).on('click', '*', ...);` - since this will catch all click events that bubble up from anywhere in the document.

Comment: @KeithRules No, for performance reasons it's best to attach delegated events to the element "closest" to the dynamically loaded elements, but to do so in the `ready` event handler, by wrapping all your code in [`$(function() { ... });`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)

Comment: `$(document)` as as i know usually used for dynamic and static elements, where `$('selector')` for static.

Comment: Could you define "dynamic" and "static" in this context, @Omar?

Comment: Thanks, @millimoose. Yeah, it's wrapped in the "document ready" thingy. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction with the Debugger docs.

Comment: I noticed something that may be just a tiny bit more specific, @millimoose. When I click on the button and it fails, I can keep clicking on it and nothing happens, UNLESS I move the mouse even by a pixel. After the mouse move, the next click triggers the event. Any idea what this may be indicating?

Comment: this example explains it better than 1000 words http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/dRhtB/

Comment: This one does work, though, @Omar: http://jsfiddle.net/dRhtB/6/

Comment: I know it does, jQuery is tricky sometimes so you have to try all possible ways. can you show some code of what you dynamically add to `body`?

Comment: Maybe, if you could find a moment, you would agree to take a look at the actual website, @Omar?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31405/discussion-between-omar-and-keithrules)

Comment: @KeithRules People usually aren't willing to look at full websites. Make a test case around your specific problem alone. (This way you might actually find what it is that's causing the problem.) This is best done by removing stuff from your actual website as long as the problem still manifests.

Comment: Agree with you, @millimoose.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
 $("html").on('click', '.mybutton', function(event) {
// do all sorts of stuff  
});
```

Here is the working example
http://jsfiddle.net/UhFsB/

Comment: @millimoose this is NOT the same code and certainly not a reason for downvote

Comment: Good point, @Spring. I made a typo. There's no such typo in the original code, though. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a CSS-related issue.